# If hash has key, use it. Otherwise, use different key

Tags: ruby, dictionary

`response` is a hash that could look like one of two things:

```
response = {'demo' => 'nil', 'test_01' => 'Demo Data'}
```

or

```
response = {'test' => 'Demo Data', 'demo' => 'nil'}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
if response.has_key? 'test_01'
    new_response.update(:nps_score  => response['test_01']
else
    new_response.update(:nps_score  => response['test']
end
```

Is there a more "Ruby" approach to this? Maybe something using the || operator? I am using ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.0.

Comment: Luigi, if I take what you say literally, `response.size => 1`, `response`'s only key is `'test_01'` or `'test'` and its single value does not depend on the key, then `new_response.update(:nps_score => response.values.first)` is all you need.  Have I misunderstood your question? Do you mean, `'test_01' => 'Demo Data 1` and `'test_01' => 'Demo Data 2`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the help - You are correct, but I edited my question to show what I really needed. The hash key/value may not always be the first pair.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what Hash's [`#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) method is for.

```
new_response.update(nps_score: response.fetch('test_01', response['test']))
```

Comment: This is more accurate. +1

Comment: Use the block form to avoid fetching a value when it may not be needed.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira: That's a good point. For anyone wondering about the tradeoffs, the block form has better best-case time, but slightly worse worst-case time. I mainly wrote it this way for readability, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
new_response.update(:nps_score => response['test_01'] || response['test'])
```

This will work unless `false` or `nil` is a valid value you may be expecting. If that's the case, you can use a ternary.

```
new_response.update(:nps_score => response.has_key?('test_01') ? response['test_01'] : response['test'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to imbue the behavior in the hash already upon construction.

```
response = Hash.new do |h, key|
  h['test'] if key == 'test_01'
end.update( 'test' => 'Demo Data', 'demo' => 'nil' )

response['test_01']
#=> 'Demo Data'
```